# How can I dynamically adjust dropdown choices based on 2 other earlier dropdown choices?

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu, switch-statement, dynamic-programming

I have 3 dropdown menus:

- Name  (static list of Device Names - `Switch` and `Laptop`)
- Brand (choices here change based on the Name chosen)
- Model  (choices here change based on the Model chosen)

My problem is that the `Switch` and `Laptop` both have same `Brand=HP` but with different `Model` choices. I need to do a `switch` case where the options for `Model` will depend on both `Name` `Brand` selection.

I have tried this type of `case` statement but it is not working:

```
case Device_Name=="Laptop" && Device_Brand=="HP": 
  document.getElementById("Model").options[0] = new Option( "--Select--", "" ); 
  document.getElementById("Model").options[1] = new Option( "Spectre x360", "Spectre x360" ); 
  document.getElementById("Model").options[2] = new Option( "Spectre Folio", "Spectre Folio" ); 
  break;
```

Here is the function I wrote to change the dropdown contents dynamically:

```js
function dynamicdropdown(listindex) {
  switch (listindex) {
    case "Laptop":
      document.getElementById("Device_Brand").options[0] = new Option( "--Select--", "" );
      document.getElementById("Device_Brand").options[1] = new Option( "Acer", "Acer" );
      document.getElementById("Device_Brand").options[2] = new Option( "HP", "HP" );
      document.getElementById("Device_Brand").options[3] = new Option( "Lenovo", "Lenovo" ); 
      break;
    case "Switch": 
      document.getElementById("Device_Brand").options[0] = new Option( "--Select--", "" );
      document.getElementById("Device_Brand").options[1] = new Option("Cisco System", "Cisco System" );
      document.getElementById("Device_Brand").options[2] = new Option( "Allied Telesis", "Allied Telesis" );
      document.getElementById("Device_Brand").options[3] = new Option( "HP", "HP" );
      break;
    case "Acer":
      document.getElementById("Model").options[0] = new Option( "--Select--", "" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[1] = new Option( "Aspire E 14", "Aspire E 14" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[2] = new Option("Nitro 5 AN515-43-R19V", "Nitro 5 AN515-43-R19V" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[3] = new Option("Aspire 3 A314-32", "Aspire 3 A314-32" );
      break;
    case "HP":
      document.getElementById("Model").options[0] = new Option( "--Select--", "" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[1] = new Option( "Spectre x360", "Spectre x360" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[2] = new Option( "Spectre Folio", "Spectre Folio" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[3] = new Option( "Chromebook 14.", "Chromebook 14." );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[4] = new Option( "Series Switch JD320B", "Series Switch JD320B" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[5] = new Option( "J9729A", "J9729A" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[6] = new Option( "H3C S3100", "H3C S3100" );
      break;
    case "Lenovo":
      document.getElementById("Model").options[0] = new Option( "--Select--", "" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[1] = new Option( "Legion Y720", "Legion Y720" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[2] = new Option( "Miix 320", "Miix 320" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[3] = new Option( "Yoga 720", "Yoga 720" );
      break;
    case "Cisco System":
      document.getElementById("Model").options[0] = new Option( "--Select--", "" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[1] = new Option( "Catalyst 2960 Series", "Catalyst 2960 Series" );
      break;
    case "Allied Telesis":
      document.getElementById("Model").options[0] = new Option( "--Select--", "" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[1] = new Option( "AT-MR820T", "AT-MR820T" );
      break;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Here is the `html` structure I'm using:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="">Device Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <div class="category_div" id="category_div">
      <select
        id="Device_Name"
        name="Device_Name"
        onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"
      >
        <option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>
        <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
        <option value="Switch">Switch</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="">Brand</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
      <select
        id="Device_Brand"
        name="Device_Brand"
        onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"
      >
        <option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="">Model</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <div class="sub_sub_category_div" id="sub_sub_category_div">
      <select id="Model" name="Model">
        <option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the problem and what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Hi sir, my problem is that Device_Name=Switch and Device_Name=Laptop both has same Device_Brand=HP but with different Models, i need to do a switch case where the options for Models will depend on both Device_Name and Device_Brand selection. I am really new on coding and my reference is always internet. But for this, i really need someone to help me out. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning sir i have tried                                                                  case Device_Name=="Laptop" && Device_Brand=="HP":
      document.getElementById("Model").options[0] = new Option( "--Select--", "" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[1] = new Option( "Spectre x360", "Spectre x360" );
      document.getElementById("Model").options[2] = new Option( "Spectre Folio", "Spectre Folio" );
      
      break;But it is not working

Comment: I have edited your question to try to make the question more clear. Please read it over to make sure I understood properly. I also attempted to reformat the code to be easier to read. As a new contributor at `stackoverflow` it's important to understand that the more clear and readable your question is, the more likely you will get assistance. Always include a statement of what you are trying to do, what isn't working, and what you've tried.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Sir thank you so much for teaching me the right way to ask question here. That would be really helpful for me in future. Yes this is the question i meant. Thank you sir.

Comment: I have an answer for you which I will post when the question is taken off of hold

Comment: Sir thank you so much sir, i will try your answer. Really appreciate it.

Comment: if you find the answer below helpful, please mark it as 'correct' (the checkmark)

Comment: Sir, earlier, i have also taught about this method, let me try and as soon as possible will 'correct' the answer, sir thank you so much for your help, these means a lot to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `case` statement must be a value that is compared to the `switch` statement parameter, not an expression as you tried.
You could combine the two values to make a new value that uniquely identifies the situation. Also it’s good to use a local variable to simplify your code and make it easier to read/understand.

Remember that with an `Option` object you specify `text` that users will see, and a `value` that they don’t. You can use the `value` to identify the brand more uniquely by using a value of “HP-Laptop” or “HP-Switch” instead of just “HP” as the brand value.

With these ideas in mind I would suggest your function change to look like this:

```js
function dynamicBrandDropdown(dropdownID, choice) {
  // finding the element once is more efficient than doing it multiple times
  const dropdown = document.getElementById(dropdownID);
  dropdown.options[0] = new Option("--Select--", "");
  // Put "-Laptop" or "-Switch" as part of each Brand's option value
  switch (choice) {
    case "Laptop":
      dropdown.options[1] = new Option("Acer", "Acer-Laptop");
      dropdown.options[2] = new Option("HP", "HP-Laptop");
      dropdown.options[3] = new Option("Lenovo", "Lenovo-Laptop");
      break;
    case "Switch":
      dropdown.options[1] = new Option("Cisco System", "Cisco-Switch");
      dropdown.options[2] = new Option("Allied Telesis", "Allied-Switch");
      dropdown.options[3] = new Option("HP", "HP-Switch");
      break;
    case "Acer-Laptop":
      dropdown.options[1] = new Option("Aspire E 14", "Aspire E 14");
      dropdown.options[2] = new Option("Nitro 5 AN515-43-R19V", "Nitro 5 AN515-43-R19V");
      dropdown.options[3] = new Option("Aspire 3 A314-32", "Aspire 3 A314-32");
      break;
    case "HP-Laptop":
      dropdown.options[1] = new Option("Spectre x360", "Spectre x360");
      dropdown.options[2] = new Option("Spectre Folio", "Spectre Folio");
      dropdown.options[3] = new Option("Chromebook 14.", "Chromebook 14.");
      break;
    case "HP-Switch":
      dropdown.options[1] = new Option("Series Switch JD320B", "Series Switch JD320B");
      dropdown.options[2] = new Option("J9729A", "J9729A");
      dropdown.options[3] = new Option("H3C S3100", "H3C S3100");
      break;
    case "Lenovo-Laptop":
      dropdown.options[1] = new Option("Legion Y720", "Legion Y720");
      dropdown.options[2] = new Option("Miix 320", "Miix 320");
      dropdown.options[3] = new Option("Yoga 720", "Yoga 720");
      break;
    case "Cisco-Switch":
      dropdown.options[1] = new Option("Catalyst 2960 Series", "Catalyst 2960 Series");
      break;
    case "Allied-Switch":
      dropdown.options[1] = new Option("AT-MR820T", "AT-MR820T");
      break;
  }
}
```